# CGBitmapContextCreate fails on background thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, cgcontext

I am trying the create a context within a background thread and it fails... This is driving me crazy :) I read everywhere that CGBitmapContextCreate is thread safe, why the function below is keeping creating a 0x0 context? It is working on the main thread of course but it's not that I want... Any clue or help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
bitmapData = malloc(width * height * 4*sizeof(GLubyte));

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace(_image);

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData,
                                width,
                                height,
                                8,
                                4*width,
                                colorspace,
                                kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,0,width, height), _image);

CGContextRelease(context);

return bitmapData;
```

Comment: does it work on the main thread?  i suspect the `colorspace` is the problem, i've seen that many times - try creating it some other way

Comment: Yes it works on the main thread, I will investigate about the colorSpace thanks a lot!